# Create Sequence Numbers with Characters when Inserting into the Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sequence

How to create sequence numbers with characters when inserting into the database?

This code is designed to use a computer equipment information storage program.
'asse_no' is a sequential number consisting of a delimiter + year + four digits.
'asse_gb' is a PC, laptop, moniter, printer, and data that is selected for storage and entered into the classification of 'asse_no' with 'PC', 'NB', 'MB', and 'PR', respectively.

Any assistance appreciated.

Code written by me

```
       {
           //make seq_no
           string year = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
           int i = 0;
           switch (cbx_asse_gb.Text)
           {
               case "PC":
                   tbx_asse_no.Text = "PC" + year + i.ToString("D4");
                   break;
               case "NB":
                   tbx_asse_no.Text = "NB" + year + i.ToString("D4");
                   break;
               case "MT":
                   tbx_asse_no.Text = "MT" + year + i.ToString("D4");
                   break;
               case "PR":
                   tbx_asse_no.Text = "PR" + year + i.ToString("D4");
                   break;
           }
this.gjmjs0TableAdapter.Insert(tbx_asse_no.Text.Trim(), tbx_asse_nm.Text.Trim(), cbx_asse_gb.Text.Trim(), tbx_juri_cd.Text, cbx_area_cd.Text, tbx_mode_nm.Text, tbx_seri_no.Text, tbx_purc_nm.Text, tbx_make_nm.Text, date_purc_date.Value, cbx_user_cd.Text, tbx_lan_ip.Text, tbx_gene_no.Text, tbx_acct_no.Text, tbx_remark.Text, cbx_flag_gb.Text, date_clos_date.Value, tbx_clos_deta.Text, bImage.ToString(), date_rent_fdate.Value, date_rent_tdate.Value, tbx_prop_flag.Text, tbx_rent_no.Text, tbx_addr.Text, purc_amt, cbx_use_mult.Text, rent_amt, date_make_date.Value, cbx_admi_cd.Text, cbx_dept_cd.SelectedValue.ToString(), tbx_asse_deta.Text, tbx_peri_devi.Text, tbx_hdd_capa.Text, tbx_cpu_size.Text, tbx_os_kind.Text, tbx_ram_capa.Text, null, null, Properties.Settings.Default.LoginIDSave, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: The easiest way is to ensure the table has an identity column which will generate a roughly sequential int, then create a computed column to add your prefix on.

Comment: The data type of 'asse_no' is 'varchar' and I can't because I don't know how you said it.

Comment: I would introduce a new C# type to encapsulate the sub-fields. Particularly if you need to parse it again. Then just store in an nvarchar database column. If you're using EF, you can define custom value mappings, or custom functions so you can query on the sub-fields too.

Comment: Ensuring the numbers are sequential, atomic, etc is a harder problem...

Comment: When a database is used by more than one user you have to use a stored procedure to make sure duplicates sequence number are not generated.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15